# How can I find where the package I loaded comes from

Tags: r, r-package

I want to programatically save some packages my script has loaded (I mean the actual directory).

I know doing `.libPaths()` shows the paths where the packages can come from (though I could also load it from somewhere different).

Is there an already build function to get where a package that I loaded comes from ?

Comment: You are searching something like `path.package()` and `find.package()` ?https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/find.package.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

```
sess.info <- sessionInfo()

names.packages <- names(sess.info$loadedOnly)

find.package(names.packages)
```

I hope this is what you are searching for.